# International Payments through Android app in India

Tags: android, paypal

I want to enable international payments possible from the app.I integrated PayPal, but even though I have money in PayPal, it's not possible to pay.

I get this error

```
{
  "name":"PAYMENT_CREATION_ERROR","debug_id":"6fbbf47861810",
  "message":"checkout-session not created",
  "information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#PAYMENT_CREATION_ERROR"
}
```

I want to know how to enable international payments.(Anybody has experience with making international payments)

Comment: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/issues/261

Comment: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Ruby-SDK/issues/34

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31258090/payment-creation-error-paypal-sdk-android

Comment: please go through these links